# Attack and Release articulation in Orchestral category of Kontakt Factory Library 2

Tags: software, articulation

I've been playing around with the new Kontakt Factory Library 2 that came with Kontakt 7. I noticed that the Strings, Brass, and Woodwind instruments are missing the Attack and Release knobs.

How do I achieve the function of tweaking of Attack and Release? Is expression curve my only option?

Comment: They promo video said they replaced the entire orchestral section with one that they've made in collaboration with a 3rd party named Orchestral Tools. Apparently the limit in feature is meant to motivate users to pay for the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You could click on the wrench in the upper left corner and then scroll down, you will see an ADSR there where you can manually tweak the Attack and Release. Don't have Kontakt 7 so not sure why it is missing those knobs.

Comment: Instead of wrenches, it's gears in the new Kontakt Factory Library 2; and it doesn't show the effects' stack.